# Read values within a XML node

Tags: php, xml

My XML document contains the following node:

> 1 macbook air and 4 ipods

My question is how to read the 'variable' values (1 and 4) and echo them with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the [simplexml](http://us.php.net/simplexml) XML parser and some regular expression.

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document>
    <description>1 macbook air and 4 ipods</description>
</document>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$description = $xml->description;
preg_match('|(\d+) macbook air and (\d+) ipods|', $description, $match);

print_r($match[1] . ' ');
print_r($match[2]);
```